# `mkdir()`: Permission denied to create folders with PHP

Tags: permissions, php

I have this PHP script:

```php
$dir = FCPATH . 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'posts'; // is in CodeIngiter
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 755);
}
```

Which creates a folder for storing posts' images. However I'm getting this error / warning:

```
Severity: Warning
Message:  mkdir(): Permission denied
```

and I can't create the folder.

How can I fix this? My folder structure looks like this:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/my-site/public/ (uploads/posts) // all folders inside files will generate in php
```

Some further information: if I comment this code, manually create the `posts` folder and then try to upload a file I get an error saying that the destination path is not writable.

Output of `ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/my-site/`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 15 lykos lykos 4096 Sep 17 23:08 application
drwxrwxrwx 6 lykos lykos 4096 Sep 29 22:00 public
drwxrwxr-x 8 lykos lykos 4096 Sep 7 12:31 system
```

Output of `ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/my-site/public`:

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 lykos lykos 4096 Sep 18 21:48 css
drwxr-xr-x 2 lykos lykos 4096 Sep 27 19:18 img
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lykos lykos 9872 Sep 17 23:04 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 8 lykos lykos 4096 Sep 27 20:06 js
drwxr-xr-x 2 lykos lykos 4096 Sep 29 20:34 uploads
```

Comment: The directory `/opt/lampp/htdocs/www/my-site/public/` needs to be owned by the same user running php

Comment: Does the folder exists already? If it doesn't, please add the output of `ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/my-site/public/uploads`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen  How can I check the user running php?

Comment: with most web servers it is www-data on Ubuntu. Who owns /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/my-site/public/uploads ? Note it is a bit of a security risk to allow php rw access.

Comment: @kos I run this command on command line and get this `total 0`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I did ls  -lah and it shows the account username I have set to login on ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your `mkdir()` call, not in Ubuntu.

As per [your comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/679844/mkdir-permission-denied-for-creating-folders-with-php/679848#comment986549_679844), `ls -l /opt/lampp/htdocs/www/my-site/public/uploads` doesn't exists, so you should call `mkdir()` passing the `recursive` parameter:

```php
$dir = '/uploads/posts';
if (!is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir, 755, true);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29852/discussion-on-answer-by-kos-mkdir-permission-denied-to-create-folders-with).